# Why do PostgreSQL examples say `+ integer '7'`?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, cast

[The PostgreSQL date functions documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) contains the following example:

```
date '2001-09-28' + integer '7'
```

Why does it consist of converting a string to an integer? Why not phrase it like this:

```
date '2001-09-28' + 7
```

Is there some tangible reason why `integer '7'` is preferable to plain old `7`?

Comment: The table is ancient, it's been maintained in essentially the same form since 7.2. It needs to be broken up into right and left operand types, like the newer [JSON table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html). Most of the Pg operator stuff is horrible unstandardized with wide variations but awesomely detailed and easy to understand. My assumption: prior to having right/left operand types on tables, they used this to show the type that the operator was expecting and just overshot on clarity and explicitness in that dynamic.

Comment: @EvanCarroll probably just trying to visually differentiate between "integer" and "interval".

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, and I don't know the answer.  My best guess is that all the other examples use the same way of casting, and someone thought it is better having it consistent.  If you are <strike>pissed off</strike> irked by this, you can scroll to the bottom of the page and send a complaint using the form linked there.